# HTTP Get Request not working with FireStore

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore, get, google-cloud-functions, http-get

I'm trying to do a GET Request to Google Firebase, I am using the Firebase-functions-helper with a try and catch, When I try to make the GET request I get the message that is inside the try, but I don`t get the data to be displayed back.
To make the GET Request I'm using postman, On postman, when doing the GET request I get this:

```
Get Success
```

This is function code:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import * as firebaseHelper from 'firebase-functions-helper/dist';
import * as express from 'express';
import * as bodyParser from 'body-parser';

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
const db = admin.firestore();

const app = express();
const main = express();

main.use(bodyParser.json());
main.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
main.use('/api/v1', app);

const sensorCollection = 'dadosusuarios';
export const webApi = functions.https.onRequest(main);

app.patch('/sensor/:sensorId', async(req, res) => {
try{
    await firebaseHelper.firestore.updateDocument(db, sensorCollection, 
 req.params.sensorId, req.body);
    res.status(200).send("Update Success");
}catch (error){
    res.status(204).send("Patch Error");
}
});

//this is the get part
app.get('/getsensor/', async(req, res) => {
try{
    await firebaseHelper.firestore.getDocument(db, sensorCollection, 
'mykey')
    .then(data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data)));
    res.status(200).send("Get Success");
}catch(error){
    res.status(204).send("Get Error");
}
});
```

**When I make a get request I would need my data to be in JSON format so I can access from Arduino**
My Firestore is composed of:

```
Collection name: dadosusuarios
Document: mydocId
Collection Fields:
          led1: false
          led2: True
          led3: false
          name: 'undefined'
          quantidade: 90
          sensores: 'sensor'
```